# Импортирование страниц в MediaWiki

Tags: база-данных, резервное-копирование, mediawiki

Всем привет, есть дамп, весит 9.5ГБ, необходимо импортировать его на новый сайт, движок так и остался MediaWiki, если загружать через стандартный способ `Служебная:Импорт` то через время выдает ошибку `Возможно, вы завершили сеанс работы. Пожалуйста, убедитесь, что вы всё ещё авторизованы, и попробуйте снова.`

Есть ли какой-то другой способ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Делайте импорт через консоль, медленно, Но точно все импортирует.
importDump.php — скрипт командной строки, расположенный в справочнике обслуживания Вашей установки MediaWiki. Если у Вас есть доступ к инсталляции MediaWiki, Вы можете вызвать его так:

```
php importDump.php <dumpfile>
```

где  имя XML файла дампа. Если файл сжат, и у него расширение .gz or .bz2, он будет развернут автоматически.

Подробнее в официальной [документации](https://m.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Importing_XML_dumps/ru).